# vuex + vuexfire - store objects would not update upon adding data

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuexfire

> in the folowing code, after i update field collection it would not
>   update "this.fields" (which is bound to tha collection in store.js by
>   vuexfire rules) - only when i  refresh page. please help. thanks

```
var newField = {
      name: this.fieldName,
      area: this.fieldArea,
      farmId: this.farmId
    }

    var docRef = fb.field.doc()
    docRef.set(newField)
    var id = docRef.id

    console.log(id)
    fb.field
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then(ref => {
        this.$store.commit('updateCurrentField', ref.data())
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

How, and where, are you getting the this.fields?

Is it a computed property?

it should be somthing arround the lines of this in order to keep the data updated ([vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html))

```
computed: {
 fields() {
   this.$store.state.fields
 }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for helping. i'm getting it using map getters like so:  ...mapGetters([fields]) inside computed, and in store.js it looks like this:   fields: state => {
      return state.fields
    },

Comment: Do you use the vue devtools? Does the store stay updated in the devtools?

Comment: i got it working by setting up the document id in the new object i created, then i added it to firestore. that's wierd, but it works this way.. thanks anyway! =)